# Stateless RNN vs stateful RNN - what should be the right batch_input_shape?

Tags: recurrent-neural-network, layer, embedding, stateful

### stateless RNN model

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
         tf.keras.layers.Embedding(input_dim=(vocab_size), output_dim=256,mask_zero=True),
         tf.keras.layers.GRU(units=1024), # stateful=True),
         tf.keras.layers.Dense(vocab_size)                           
])
```

### stateful RNN model equivalent

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
         tf.keras.layers.Embedding(input_dim=(vocab_size), output_dim=256, batch_input_shape=(batch_size, None), mask_zero=True),
         tf.keras.layers.GRU(units=1024, stateful=True),
         tf.keras.layers.Dense(vocab_size)                           
])
```

stateless version works fine.  stateful version throws error with wrong input shape.  batch_size is set to 32.  Any help would be appreiated.

Thanks in advance.